# Find first in where clause MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I've googled and searched here and maybe I don't know the exact way to write the question but can't find an answer...

I need to find the sum of credits from click_stats where source = 'reward' for all users who have claimed at least one of the 3 promo codes AND have the total clicks displayed. There are many more than the 3 but simplifed what I need to try to meet posting criteria.

Tables:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| click_stats                                 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| ID | Credits | Userid | Source | Clicked    |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 1  | 10      | jon    | reward | 1602216005 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 2  | 5       | bob    | reward | 1602216504 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 3  | 5       | jon    | reward | 1602216137 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 4  | 5       | bob    | reward | 1602216138 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 5  | 10      | jon    | reward | 1602216139 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 6  | 5       | jon    | reward | 1602216140 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 7  | 10      | bob    | reward | 1602216150 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 8  | 10      | jon    | reward | 1602216150 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 9  | 10      | sue    | reward | 1602216150 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| 10  | 10     | sue    | prize  | 1602216150 |
+----+---------+--------+--------+------------+
```

```
+-----------------------+
| promo_used            |
+----+--------+---------+
| id | userid | promoid |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  | bob    | 1       |
+----+--------+---------+
| 2  | bob    | 2       |
+----+--------+---------+
| 3  | bob    | 3       |
+----+--------+---------+
| 4  | jon    | 1       |
+----+--------+---------+
| 5  | jon    | 2       |
+----+--------+---------+
```

```
+------------------------+
| promo_codes            |
+----+----------+--------+
| id | code     | reward |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | forever1 | 20     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | novgfy1  | 250    |
+----+----------+--------+
| 3  | novgfy2  | 500    |
+----+----------+--------+
```

My Query:

```
SELECT 
    click_stats.userid  as Name, 
    sum(credits) as TotalClicks 
  FROM click_stats
    JOIN promo_used 
    ON click_stats.userid = promo_used.userid
    JOIN promo_codes 
        ON promo_used.promoid = promo_codes.id
WHERE
   click_stats.source = 'reward' 
   and FROM_UNIXTIME(clicked) > '2020-10-09' 
   and (promo_codes.name like '%forever%' 
        or promo_codes.name like 'novgfy%')
group by 
   Name
having 
   TotalClicks > 10
```

Results when I run my query (returning the total number of clicks * number of promo codes used):

```
+--------------------+
| Results            |
+------+-------------+
| Name | TotalClicks |
+------+-------------+
| bob  | 60          |
+------+-------------+
| jon  | 80          |
+------+-------------+
```

Results I am wanting (the total number of clicks only):

```
+--------------------+
| Expected Results   |
+------+-------------+
| Name | TotalClicks |
+------+-------------+
| bob  | 20          |
+------+-------------+
| jon  | 40          |
+------+-------------+
```

The problem (I suspect) is that it is summing the click_stats every time it finds a match for promo_codes.name. I just need to know if one of them has been used and then return the total clicks for that user.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. Your query references 4 tables that we know nothing about.

Comment: Thanks GMB, I have added some more details to my original question.

Comment: As @GMB requested, **please provide sample data and expected results**. That's part of the [mre] that this site requires.

Comment: I added an example with expected results. Not sure what kind of sample data is needed. If this is not correct, I'll just delete the question and continue searching and come back here when I understand how it works better. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't join `click_stats` to the other tables because you will multiply the rows that you get by a factor equal to the number of rows of each user in `promo_used`.
Instead use the operator `IN` to filter the users:

```
SELECT Userid, SUM(Credits) TotalClicks 
FROM click_stats
WHERE source = 'reward' 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(clicked) > '2020-10-09'
  AND Userid IN (
    SELECT pu.Userid 
    FROM promo_used pu INNER JOIN promo_codes pc
    ON pc.id = pu.promoid
    WHERE pc.code like '%forever%' OR pc.code like 'novgfy%' 
  )
GROUP BY Userid 
HAVING TotalClicks > 10
```

Or:

```
SELECT Userid, SUM(Credits) TotalClicks 
FROM click_stats
WHERE source = 'reward' 
  AND FROM_UNIXTIME(clicked) > '2020-10-09'
  AND Userid IN (
    SELECT pu.Userid FROM promo_used pu 
    WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM promo_codes pc
      WHERE pc.id = pu.promoid AND (pc.code like '%forever%' OR pc.code like 'novgfy%' )
    ) 
  )
GROUP BY Userid
HAVING TotalClicks > 10
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=33bf75d7fa29fff46396cd58c87c1131).
Results:

```
> Userid | TotalClicks
> :----- | ----------:
> bob    |          20
> jon    |          40
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for.